# Form validation with express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have read that form validations on client-side is not enough to prevent any malicious actions from users. For that case i have read that is needed to validate the form on the server-side too. Since i am first time using express, can someone give me a clue for what i need to do?

I'm leaving here the html form and the js validation function. My form doesn't have the "action" and "methods" for test purposes. I know that the "action" leads to my validation page and the method is POST on this specific case.

Is it safer to create a module for the validation and then call it on the server.js? or can i code it inside of the server.js?

**HTML**

```
     <div class="containerfrm" id="frmcntn">
     <!--Form Creation with method POST, JavaScript input validations and php file validation-->
     <form action="" method="" class="cntbox" id="formBoard" name="formOfBoard" onsubmit="validateIndexForm(event)">
     <!--Close Button of the pop up-->
                    <div class="righttopicon" onclick="closeForm()">
                        <img src="images/square-x.png" alt="close icon">
                    </div>

                    <!--Form with the necessary inputs (Name of the Board, IP Address, Port and upload file). All the inputs are required-->
                    <div class="col-100">
                        <h3>Add new board:</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!--Input for the boards name with max length of 50 characters-->
                            <div class="col-75">
                                <label for="bname">Name of the Board: *</label><br>
                                <input type="text" id="boardname" name="boardname" placeholder="Ex: Board 1" maxlength="50">
                            </div>
                            <!--Input for the IP Address that can only accept IP's and with a max length of 15 characters-->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-75">
                                    <label for="ipadd">IP Address: *</label><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="ipadd" id="ipaddress" placeholder="Ex: 192.168.1.1" maxlength="15">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--Input for the Port that can only accept numbers with a max length of 4-->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-75">
                                    <label for="portnum">Port: *</label><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="portnum" id="portnum" placeholder="Ex: 8080" maxlength="4" minlength="2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--Input for the upload of the boards image that can only accept .png files-->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-75">
                                    <label for="imgadd">Upload image:</label><br>
                                    <img src="images/file-upload.png" alt="Insert image" class="insrtimg" name="imageboard" id="insertimage">
                                    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename" onchange="fileValidation(event)">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--'Save' and 'Discard' buttons -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-80">
                                    <div class="btnformcontainer">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btnfrm btnconfrm" value="Save">
                                        <div class="btnfrm btndel"  onclick="discardValues()">Discard</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

**JS Validation**

```
function validateIndexForm(event){
    let x = document.getElementById("boardname").value;
    let y = document.getElementById("ipaddress").value;
    let z = document.getElementById("portnum").value;
    let w = document.getElementById("myFile").value;

    let ipformat = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;;
    
    if(x == ""){
        //prevent the form submit
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Please insert the boards name");
        return false;
    }
    if(!y.match(ipformat) && !y === "localhost"){
        //prevent the form submit
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Please insert a valid IP address");
        return false;
    }
    if(z != isNaN() && !(z > 0)){
        //prevent the form submit
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Please insert the correct port");
        return false;
    }
    if(w == ""){
       event.preventDefault();
        alert("Please insert a valid image");
        return false;
    }
    return x, y, z, w;
}
```

The uploaded file is getting validated on other function successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you create a module for the validation and bring it in to your server file *or* code the logic directly into your server file, it does not affect security and produces the same behavior.

For securing your server-side form validation, I recommend a tool like [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/) in combination with a body-parser.

Check out this [article](https://raddy.dev/blog/node-js-form-validation-using-express-validator-and-ejs/) for a hands-on approach to the above mentioned setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the same thing in the post request code on your server side.

Ex:

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  let username = req.body.username;
  let password = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(req.body.password).digest('base64');
  let repassword = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(req.body.repassword).digest('base64');
if(password != repassword) return res.redirect('/login');
});
```

You can also do queries in your redirect like this:

> res.redirect('/login/?e=4&t=l');

And parse them client side to display errors like passwords do not match.